# Catching Button Events from Different ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, core-graphics, protocols

**My Setup**

I have a `ViewController`, where users type some sort of text in there. Call it `InputViewController`.

I have a `UIView` (in a separate class), where I draw a navigation bar that has a gradient (I override `drawRect` for Core Graphics, hence I need to to have in a separate class) which has a button. The button takes you to a `MapViewController`, which allows you to add a location tag to your input. Once a location tag is added, I would like to change the button's image.

**My Problem**

Once the button is tapped, I need to send the user's input to the `MapViewController`, where a delegate is also implemented and will pass back some information back to the `InputViewController`. The issue here is that the button resides in the separate `UIView`. One way to do this is pass the `UIView` the information once they are set, which in turn would be passed to the `MapViewController` once the button is tapped. The problem here would be the delegate as the delegate needs to return to the `InputViewController` and not the `UIView.

I was wondering if its possible to move the `UIView` into the `InputViewController`, including the `drawRect` method for that view. If so, how can I do that? If not, what are other ways/suggestions I can do to have the above set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to use NSNotifications for sending messages to your classes. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).